# std::bind lose reference when delivered as rvalue reference

Tags: c++, stdbind

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
auto callback(T&& func) ->decltype(func())
{
    return func();
}

double test(double& value)
{
    value=value+1.0;
    return value;
}

int main(void)
{
    double t=1.0;
    printf("%f\n",t);
    test(t);
    printf("%f\n",t);
    callback(std::bind(test,t));
    printf("%f\n",t);
}
```

And it outputs

```
1.000000
2.000000
2.000000
```

Which implies the `callback` function got a copy of `t` instead of a reference to `t`. I am wondering what happened, since for `std::bind` it should be perfect-forwarding.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`std::bind` uses value semantics by default. It's a sane default that lets you do things like the following safely.

```
int f(double x);

auto fun = std::bind(f, 1.0); // stores a copy, not a reference to a temporary
fun();
```

Using value semantics is safe: the lifetime of the bound arguments becomes the lifetime of the object returned by bind. Using reference semantics would not have that guarantee. So you are required to be explicit when you want reference semantics; if you get in trouble then it's your fault. In order to do that you need to use `std::ref`:

```
int main(void)
{
    double t=1.0;
    printf("%f\n",t);
    test(t);
    printf("%f\n",t);
    callback(std::bind(test, std::ref(t)));
    printf("%f\n",t);
}
```

This same protocol is used elsewhere in the standard library, like the `std::thread` constructor.

Answer (score 8):

`std::bind()` is designed for value semantics ([as R. Martinho Fernandes nicely explains in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432100/1932150)), and *does* create copies internally. What you need/want is [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
callback(std::bind(test, std::ref(t)));
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`std::ref` returns an [`std::reference_wrapper<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) object that wraps a reference to your original argument. This way, the `reference_wrapper` object around `t` gets copied, and not `t` itself.

This allows you to choose between value semantics (assumed by default) and reference semantics (which requires your explicit intervention).

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e0020435b4596283ce7ec98fb54b11a8-4c7a93babd200e4d38472bfd414f71ce).